# Verify UK citizenship

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, brexit

I read an article about UK settled status, and one group at risk of not getting settled status is people who *believe* they have UK citizenship and therefore need not apply for settled status, but either they are wrong and don't actually have UK citizenship, or the UK government doesn't think they have UK citizenship. The article also says that many of these could successfully apply for settled status, but they might not do so because they think they don't need to.

What should a person who wants to live in the UK and believes they have UK citizenship do to make sure that the UK government actually either agrees or disagrees?

Comment: Do any of the people in question have British passports?

Comment: @patriciashanahan How is that relevant? If they have a UK passport that is irrefutable proof that the British government accepted then as citizens, no?

Comment: @DiegoSánchez Some countries have been known to change their minds after granting a passport. There is currently a problem with the US retroactively changing standards for proof of being born in the US. If there have been no cases of the UK doing that, getting a passport is a good way to resolve the issue.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I'm reading this more in the context of the Windrush Scandal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windrush_scandal), but I understand your concerns now.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez, The UK government has revoked passports or refused to renew them when they've determined that the passport was 'given in error'. A passport is an identify document. It is not 'irrefutable proof' of citizenship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Patricia Sanahan's comment, the easiest and most straightforward way to both verify and prove your citizenship would be to [apply for a British passport](https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-adult-passport).

If they grant it, you have the ultimate documental proof.

If they reject it, they will tell you why.

**Edit after MJeffryes' comment**: Turns out that it may not be that ultimate after all, the UK's government has at times [denied passport renewals to it's own citizens](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-45270554).

Comment: *If they grant it, you have the ultimate documental proof.* I agree that this is the best option. However, the British government sometimes [denies passport renewals](https://www.ft.com/content/c98dbf6c-8503-11e8-96dd-fa565ec55929). That is, a passport was previously issued, but the Home Office changes its mind about citizenship status when renewal is requested. A British passport is therefore not irrevocable proof of citizenship.

Comment: What actually happened in this case: Children of immigrants were affected. To get a passport for them, parents had to send in documents A, B and C. Document C was quite pointless and was never verified; kids got their passport with documents A and B only and parents were not told C was missing. The requirement for document C has since been abolished. The jobs worths in the Home Office now denied passport renewal to anyone not providing document C. Which is impossible to get now because it is supposed to not be required. This can only be explained with malice.